# NodeJS, mongoDB, angularJS nested comment system

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, nested, comments

I'm programming a little nested comment system. I have followed the rules in this mongoDB case study http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/ about storing comments. I have chosen to store each comment in a single document.

When in my interface I ask for a discussion I get an ordered array of comments in a discussion from my API. The thing is, I'm very stucked in constructing some kind of object with the nested comments, to know the levels so I can render it with AngularJS.
I know I can easily render it if I have a big JSON or Object with the entire discussion and the replies nested to their parents. So my Schema looks like:

```
var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  discussion_id: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  parent_id: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
  slug: String,
  full_slug: String,
  community: {type: String, default: 'defaultCommunity'},
  inserted: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  title: String,
  text: String,
  author: {
    id: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    twitter_id: SchemaTypes.Long,
    twitter_screen_name: String,
    twitter_profile_pic: String
  },
  updated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  hearts: {type: Number, default: 0},
  dislikes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  flags: {type: Number, default: 0},
});
```

So when I recover a discussion from the client-side I receive an array with all the docs representing all the comments. The slug represent a "path" to the comment, for example:

- parent_slug: 834b
- child_slug: 834b/123k
- child_child_slug: 834b/123k/876t
- child_slug: 834b/656m

I hope someone could throw some light into this, because I'm really stucked. The easy solution is to store the entire discussion in a single document but I wanted to do it this way.

Thank you very much.

Comment: any updates on this?

Comment: Yeah @Maury Markowitz I solved this but I can't remember now. I think I have the code in an old repository so let me search for it and I will post the solution. It was a bit of an angular hack.